# Fluctuating line graph in pfgplots

Tags: pgfplots

I'd like to plot the following function between 0 and 0.5 using pgfplots.

[image: function to plot]

However I get as a result the fluctuating line in picture. I'd like to get a smooth line, as the function is.

Is this a numerical approximation error?

Here is a mwe

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[axis x line=middle, axis y line=middle,
             width=\linewidth, height=0.5\linewidth,
             xmin = 0, xmax=0.5]
    \addplot[smooth, domain=0:0.5, samples = 100] {
        exp(0.1*x)-sin(deg(0.1*x))
    }; 
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Result I get]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, these are numerical issues. In what follows I describe two ways to resolve them: using `lualatex` as compiler or using `xfp` for the computation. Both of them give smooth results, which agree.

Once I add `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}` and compile

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[axis x line=middle, axis y line=middle,
             width=\linewidth, height=0.5\linewidth,
             xmin = 0, xmax=0.5]
    \addplot[smooth, domain=0:0.5, samples = 100] {
        exp(0.1*x)-sin(deg(0.1*x))
    }; 
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

with `lualatex` I get

[image]

If you do not want to use `lualatex` you could employ `xfp` instead.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{xfp}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \X [count=\Y] in {0,0.005,...,0.5}
{\ifnum\Y=1
\xdef\Lst{(\X,\fpeval{exp(0.1*\X)-sin(0.1*\X)})}
\else
\xdef\Lst{\Lst (\X,\fpeval{exp(0.1*\X)-sin(0.1*\X)})}
\fi}
    \begin{axis}[axis x line=middle, axis y line=middle,
             width=\linewidth, height=0.5\linewidth,
             xmin = 0, xmax=0.5,ytick=\empty]
    \addplot[smooth,no marks]  coordinates {\Lst}; 
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]